# Does this Taylor series correspond to an Analytical function and how do I determine which?

Tags: calculus, summation

I have a Taylor series given by:
$$ \sum_k^{\infty} {2k\choose k} (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$

Does this correspond to a nice, closed-form analytical formula? And is there a method by which I could determine this?

Comment: I don’t believe there’s a nice form for $\sum \frac{x^k}{(k!)^2}$

Comment: Have a look at the many Bessel functions. One of them definitely corresponds with your series.

Comment: It is the Bessel function $J_0$. See equation (78): https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html

Comment: I'd recommend giving [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B%28-1%29%5Ek+Binomial%5B2k%2Ck%5Dx%5E%282k%29%2F%282k%29%21%2C%7Bk%2C0%2CInfinity%7D%5D) a try with these sorts of questions. As you can see, it can sum the series and indeed finds it is $J_0$.

Comment: Thanks, that would be correct. I will use WolframAlpha in future